# Would this SOT-23 P-FET be appropriate for reverse current protection with current up to 1A?

Tags: circuit-protection

I've designed in reverse current protection on a board that I'm designing. The input voltage is 24V with a potential max current draw of 1A (depends on what is plugged in, parts of the PCB are modular).
[image]

Here is the P-FET
https://docs.rs-online.com/7785/0900766b80f35049.pdf

According to the datasheet the Max continuous current drain is 2.3A at ambient vgs@10V . The package seems too small to support currents in the ampere range. Would this be an appropriate choice for this circuit or do I need to go for a bigger package with higher current drain?
thanks

Comment: If you doubt the manufacturers specification, order one and test it out ?

Comment: Reverse current or reverse polarity? There is a difference between connecting input voltage backwards and having that reverse polarity push current into the circuit versus the load side dumping power and pushing a reverse current back to the source. A simple diode protects against both. A simple PMOS circuit like yours only protects against the former. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525248/is-this-mosfet-upside-down/525249#525249 Also think about what voltages appear between PMOS pins if you connect 24V in reverse. Vds isn't the only max voltage rating.

Comment: @DKNguyen while a diode does both, it will also produce a lot of heat at currents above 1A. This circuit is really only intended to be a simple way to protect the board if upon installation the power is put in backwards .Thanks, I'll check the link out.

Comment: I know. I wasn't suggesting you replace it with a diode. Just suggesting some things are taken for granted with a diode.

Comment: Interesting, looking at the link I hadn't considered the possibly of the load pushing power to the source. Not an issue in my application, but something I'll bear in mind.

Comment: Usually current limits are specified with a *huge* thermal pad (typically 1sq/in or 6sq/cm, read note 3 on the datasheet). The rdson at 0.165 is not really great and 100°C/W is typical for a SOT23.  At 2.3A it's 800mW which is about +90°C of heating. I agree with the datasheet. It all depends on your Ta and current needs

Answer (score 1):

Absolute maximum rated G-S voltage is +/-20V and you're apply 24V (plus any transients). That could have reliability consequences. It can be fixed with a zener.

The 100K is rather high- you'll have quite slow switching so the MOSFET SOA limits may be violated.

Also, keep in mind that there are probably static brown-out conditions (input voltage) that could cause the MOSFET to neatly unsolder itself and fall off the board.

Comment: I added a 6V Zener as it seemed quite difficult to get an appropriate FET with a G-S of more than +/-20V .Most of what I was looking at are rated at +/-15V

Comment: @ChrisD91 You are forgetting zeners act as a short and will clamp the voltage to the load 6V as it fries. Reposition the zener so it only clamps Vgs and not Vout.

Comment: @ChrisD91 Why wouldn't you use a 12V zener when the MOSFET is already a bit on the high side in Rds(on)? More voltage = lower Rds(on).

Comment: @DKNguyen Zener goes from gate to source.

Comment: My comment was meant for OP, sorry.

Comment: I just realised the layout mistake, thanks for pointing it out! Also, I'm using a 6V Zener for another part of the circuit so I was looking to keep the BOM smaller. I can always swap for 12V if it would make a difference.

Comment: Surface tension should be enough to retain a desoldered SOT23  :)  it depends on the vibration I guess,